# Is there a way to block a live chat script/widget from appearing on certain posts/pages in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an online store and also have a blog on the same domain.  I have a live chat service that I use.  The script is loaded onto each page via a Wordpress plugin and the chat widget loads on every page.

However, I have no need for that widget to appear on my blog posts.

Is there a way to block that script from loading on my blog post pages or only certain ones?  The chat service support has not been helpful.

Thanks for any tips!
Chris

Comment: You need to provide information about what chat service you are using. Also since this is a plugin specific question, it is unlikely you will receive a answer.

Comment: Okay thank you.  It's called PureChat.  I don't necessarily have to use the plugin.  Let's say I install their script code in my header.php file and do not use the plugin.  Is there a way to block the widget from appearing on certain posts or all posts?

Comment: Sure, WP have methods that help you indentify what section is being called. You can add those methods to your template and only place the PureChat header when you need. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page for example.

Comment: Post what you have tried and I will see what I can do for your :)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments to your question, the WordPress is_*() functions are your friend in this case.

Without actually seeing your site or its structure, I am winging my answer a bit with the assumptions that you do not want the chat widget to appear on your blog posts and root blog page (/blog/) but everywhere else.

In the spot where you have the code, try the following:

```
if (!is_singular('post') || !is_page('blog')) {
      // Code for Chat Widget Here
}
```

What this code tells WordPress is to check and see if the current document is either a post-type of 'post' or a page with the slug 'blog'. If both of these conditions are met, then your chat widget code will be processed, otherwise nothing will happen.

The is_singular() function can take an array value as well so if there are multiple post-types you want excluded or something you can replace ('post') with (array('post', 'product'))

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Right.  I am just trying to keep it off of all blog posts and blog page.  I just tried the code you gave but it still keeps showing on my posts.  Is there anything I can tell you or show you about the site or structure that would help you?

Comment: Is it at least not showing up on the /blog/ page? Also, are you using the default post type for your blog posts or a custom one?

Comment: Okay, here is what I put and made my site go into a 500 internal server error.  I obviously have something wrong.  Can you advise?   <php?
if (!is_singular('post') || !is_page('blog')) {
//chat script
}
?>

Comment: Yes, it's an established site.  I just removed the code and it's working again.  No big deal.  I know Wordpress very well but have a lot to learn about coding